# How to implement Full Text search in InnoDB?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a query,

e.g.

name column have "Rodrigue Dattatray Desilva".

I want to write a query in such a way that,

If I search for 'gtl' and match anywhere in string it should show the result.

I know in PHP I can apply the patch like '%g%t%l%'.

But I want to know MySql way.

Note: I can search for anything, I am just giving above an example.

**EDIT**:

```
create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100));
insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Rodrigue Dattatray Desilva");

select * from Test where title like '%g%t%l%';
```

Consider the above case. Where "gtl" is string I am trying to search in the title but search string can be anything.
gtl is string where it exists in the current title but not in sequence.

Comment: I think ´STRCMP()´ is what you want. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is that you need an extra wildcard:

```
select * from Test where title like '%g%t%l%';
```

The query you posted does not have a wild card after the 'l', so would only match if the phrase ended with 'l'.

The more complicated answer is that you can also use [regular expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html), which give you more power over the search.

The *even* more complicated answer is that performance of these string matching queries tends to be poor - the wild cards mean that indexes are usually ineffective. If you have a large number of rows in your table, [full-text searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) is much faster.

Comment: I noticed and made changes in question. But may be full text search is solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same in Mysql too.

You can use the keyword *like* in MySql.

% - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters

_ - The underscore represents a single character